# How to use "regular expression" to separate specific strings in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, regular-expression, split

I have a string `'(1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1)'`, and I need to use a regular expression to have this output:

```
field1   field2  level
  1        30      1
  2         4      2
  52        0      3
  8         1      4
```

The query I've wrote so far is:

```
select distinct trim(regexp_substr('1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1','[^:,]+',1,level)) repfield,level lvl
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1', '[^:,]+', 1, level) is not null
 order by lvl
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what does the `level` column mean? Is it an `id`? **E.G:** row 1 = level 1, row 2 = level 2, row *n* = level *n*?

Comment: Isn't there a convention of using upper case for the SQL keywords (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc.)?

Comment: @LogicalBranch Yes. It's kind of like an id . you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple method:

```
col field1 format a6
col field2 format a6
col lvl format a3
variable B1 varchar2(32);
exec :B1 := '1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1';
select
  regexp_substr(regexp_substr(:B1, '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^:]+', 1) field1,
  regexp_substr(regexp_substr(:B1, '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^:]+', 2) field2, 
  level lvl from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:B1, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

FIELD1 FIELD2 LVL
------ ------ ---
1      30       1
2      4        2
52     2        3
8      1        4
```

Or with fewer `regexp_substr` calls:

```
col field1 format a6
col field2 format a6
col lvl format a3
variable B1 varchar2(32);
exec :B1 := '1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1';
select
  regexp_substr(:B1, '[^:,]+', 1, level*2 - 1 ) field1,
  regexp_substr(:B1, '[^:,]+', 1, level*2) field2,
  level lvl from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:B1, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

FIELD1 FIELD2 LVL
------ ------ ---
1      30       1
2      4        2
52     0        3
8      1        4
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11-g and it gives me this error : Invalid sql statement . Would you mind editing your answer please?

Comment: @PanteaTourang There is nothing to edit. The above works fine in 11g as well. The error is thrown most likely by your client handling the statements differently. Use SQL*Plus and Oracle SQL Developer. Anything else is suboptimal. The above is from SQL Developer 19.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as
( select distinct trim(regexp_substr('1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1,90:54', '[^,]+', 1, level)) repfield,
  level lvl
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('1:30,2:4,52:0,8:1,90:54', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not  null
 order by lvl)
 select 
   SUBSTR(repfield,1,instr(repfield , ':')-1) AS Field1,
   SUBSTR(repfield,instr(repfield,':')+1,length(repfield)) as field2,
   lvl
 from cte
```

Thanks for you're answer. I came to another way to solve this. I could not use regular expressions (I did not have enough information) so i used `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` instead